# Modifying the $scope in a callback within a controller function

Tags: angularjs

Here is my Angular.js controller function code:

```
myControllers.controller("TreeDataController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

    $scope.greeting = "TreeDataController";

    treeDataSource.getData("123", function (rootNode) {
        // this is the callback when the AJAX operation succeeds, rootNode is a JSON object which contains hierarchical data.
        $scope.tree = rootNode;

        console.log("Got rootNode.");

        $scope.foobar = "baz";

    }, function (e) { alert(e); });

}]);
```

Here is my View:

```
<h2>Queries</h2>
{{greeting}}
{{foobar}}
<script type="text/ng-template" id="treeItemRenderer.html">
    {{node.name}}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="node in node.value" ng-include="''treeItemRenderer.html''"></li>
    </ul>
</script>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="node in tree" ng-include="''treeItemRenderer.html''">
        {{node.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I run this page in Chrome, the page displays "TreeDataController" in the `{{greeting}}` placeholder, and the console reports it got the data (see my `console.log` call), however the tree data is never displayed. I thought it was a problem with my recursive-template so I added `$scope.foobar = "baz";` and `{{foobar}}`, however that isn't populated either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common error you can get when dealing with Angular.
Because you're updating the $scope outside of a scope apply, you aren't actually causing Angular to do any template rerendering.
This is fairly simple to fix, wrap any $scope calls within `$scope.$apply`, see the following:

```
treeDataSource.getData("123", function (rootNode) {
  $scope.$apply(function () {
    $scope.tree = rootNode;
    console.log("Got rootNode.");
    $scope.foobar = "baz";
  });

}, function (e) { alert(e); });
```